How to change Namespaces, File names and in code words from a GitHub Templates
Where I work we have a C# Template for microservies at GitHub named "Work.Template" to guide all of our new projects.
The workflow we adapted is to clone the Template repository and replace all the "Template" inside the files using replace and SyncNameSpaces functions from Visual Studio and for the file names we do it manually for whatever name we want.
But this method is flawed because every time some of the replaces doesn't work as planned and results in more manual work and waste of a time we don't have.
We do a "find" in the solution and replace Template for the new name
after that we replace these "Template" ->

for the new name
and finally we do it by hand in the files explorer ->

To check if every thing is working we build the application and check for the errors
I am curious to know if there is a method that I can do which receives the new name and replace the old one in all the files (inside it or not).
